# How can I get data from a specific field with a composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, composite

I have three tables, sketched below. The showid and actorid from the Shows-Actors table comes from the id column in the Shows and Actors table. They combine to form a composite primary key - An actor can be in many shows, and shows can have many different actors.

```
_______         _______        _______________ 
|Actors |       |Shows|        |Shows-Actors  |  
---------       ---------       --------------
|id|name|       |id|name|      |actorid|showid|
---------       ---------      ---------------
|1 |Bob |       |1 |GoT |      |    1 |1      |
---------       ---------      ----------------
|2 |Lou|        |2 |TWD |      |    1 |2      |
---------       ---------      ----------------
```

On one site page I want to display a list of all actors names, as well as all the shows they appear in. E.g. With the data above, The page would display:
1. Bob. Shows: GoT, TWD.
2. Lou. Shows: ...etc.

Currently I have the list of actors displaying correctly, But i'm stuck on how I'd use the composite PK to get a list of all the shows each actor has appeared in.
Here is what I have so far, in terms of code relevant to this question.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Shows-Actors`
          INNER JOIN `Actors`   
          ON `Actors`.`id` = `Shows-Actors`.`acid`
          ORDER BY `Actors`.`name` ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($actor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    print '<tr>';   
    print '<td>'.$actor['name'].'</td>';
    //Insert all shows that actor appears in here
    print '</tr>';
}
```

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just join the `Shows` table like this:

```
SELECT 
    Actors.`name`,
    Shows.`name`,
FROM `Shows-Actors`
INNER JOIN `Actors`   
    ON `Actors`.`id` = `Shows-Actors`.`acid`
INNER JOIN Shows
    ON Shows.id = `Shows-Actors`.showid
ORDER BY `Actors`.`name` ASC
```